# Como pegar valor do atributo do elemento com IONIC4 Angular

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic4, atributos

Como posso pegar o valor do atributo do conjunto de dados ou alterá-lo no link com a seguinte estrutura:

```
<a href='#' data-set='22'>Texto</a>
```

Eu sei que no jquery eu posso usar o:

```
$('a').Attr('conjunto de dados');
```

E para alterar seu conteúdo:

```
$('a').Attr('conjunto de dados', '01');
```

Mas no Ionic4 não estou conseguindo, já pesquisei e não consigo exatamente isso.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Mas vc está utilizando Ionic com o que? Javascript puro, Angular, React, Vue??

Comment: estou usando com Angular

Comment: E o que vc conhece de Angular?

Comment: Estou iniciando no ionic4 com angular. Mas ja sei basta te coisas. Você pode ajudar?

Comment: Então José, vc pode pegar o valor do atributo `href` ou qualquer outro valor de qualquer outro atributo com Javascript puro normal ou então com Angular mesmo com um **@Viewchild** por exemplo.

Comment: LeAndrade muito obrigado por contribuir.
Nesse caso como posso pegar ou alterar o atributo href com o uso do  @Viewchild por exemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu consegui assim:

```
<ion-input #myInput data-set="01"></ion-input>

@ViewChild ('myInput', { read: ElementRef }) myInput: ElementRef;


ngAfterContentInit() {
   console.log(this.myInput.nativeElement.dataset.dta1); 
}
```

Funcionando certinho com IONIC4 e Angular4.

Muito obrigado pela contribuição @LeAndrade

Comment: Não precisa escrever resolvido, bastar clicar no check ao lado da resposta. +1 por usar dataset

Comment: Valeu Guilerme! Muito obrigado.